# How do I query for all polygons within a distance from a point?

Tags: distance, geodjango, spatialite

Call me stupid, but somehow I couldn't figure out how to do the following.

I've got a testing shapefile with 18 features, which I successfully imported into [GeoDjango](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/gis/) (1.3, running on Spatialite). As an practical example, I've taken a centroid of one of them (`area.mpoly.centroid`) and tried to find all areas within a 20 km distance (touching would be enough, needn't cover complete area).

```
Area.objects.filter(mpoly__dwithin=(centroid, D(km=20)))
```

However, this only gives me an empty list. Increasing the number to 200 km (in theory, this should cover all of my dataset) also yields nothing.

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: If you're trying to do this in ArcGIS prior to the import, I believe you want to write a command to make a 20 km buffer around your points, then do an intersect between the polygon layer and your buffer. Sorry, I don't know any programming, but that's how I'd do it using tools in ESRI. Does that help at all?

Comment: @Dano: no, sorry, I need to do this in GeoDjango.

Answer (score 1):

I missed this before, you're using SpatialLite. [dwithin is not supported with SpatialLite](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/gis/geoquerysets/#std%3afieldlookup-dwithin).

---

Old answer:
'Area' is a GeoDjango class. You probably have a name conflict. Don't name your models with the same name of any GeoDjango classes.

Also, 'centroid' should not be used as a variable name for the same reason.

Comment: code above is not the exact copy of my code, I've changed the specific model name to `Area`, likewise with `centroid`, both shouldn't be a problem as long as the imports are correct. It's not a naming conflict.